# Tomcat seems to not be able to deallocate threads

Tags: java, tomcat, java-8

on my tomcat I set maxThreads=300 on the connector.
During a request peak I can see about 180 threads were allocated to serve the requests and that's fine. However, after 2 hours, the 180 threads are still inside of the VM even though the requests dropped.

Is there a way to control after how much time the tomcat/JVM cleans the unused threads?

**Edit**
This is my connector configuration (I updated the maxThreads to 300 in the meantime):

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" maxThreads="300"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Comment: pls show us your full connector configuration

Comment: done, it is very basic actually

Comment: have you tried to set `maxIdleTime` see Kayaman's proposal

Comment: @Phate , Its bit old question but just wondering if you can provide inputs now. Even we are facing same issue, where tomcat threads are not coming down after load decreases. They are staying in idle state and waiting for Tasks. Did you fix this issue using Executor or any other way ? Though in our lower environments, its works fine and when we did load test in lower environments, threads come down to initial numbers within 3-5 minutes. Its getting difficult to reproduce the scnerios.

Answer (score 3):

The [Connector](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html) element doesn't have too much configuration related to the request threads besides `maxThreads`, but if you configure an [Executor](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/executor.html) you can set the `maxIdleTime` explicitly and verify whether the threads really can't be closed or not.

Comment: Was my first thought. But the default `maxIdleTime` is 1 min. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/executor.html

Comment: @dit that's the default for an `Executor`, and while it would be reasonable to expect that `Connector` shares the same defaults (although only `maxThreads` attribute is shared by them), this let's you *explicitly* set the `maxIdleTime` for verification.

Comment: Would it be a best practice to use an executor instead of the default? Has this approach any downside?

Comment: @Phate executors can be shared between connectors, that's the major difference. It's the only way you can access the more specific attributes (it seems). Why did you update `maxThreads` to `300`? First you were worried that the threads weren't being closed down, but now you increased the max limit? Have you any idea what you're doing?

Comment: I need to close the threads but also be able to serve a large number of requests during the peak time...after about 4h the number of threads started to drop, it seems it is just very slow.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the connection pool timeout on your connector, [check it out](https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/common_howto/timeouts.html#Connection%20Pools%20and%20Idle%20Timeouts)

> We generally recommend values around 10 minutes, so setting
>   connection_pool_timeout to 600 (seconds). If you use this attribute,
>   please also set the attribute keepAliveTimeout (if it is set
>   explicitly) or connectionTimeout in the AJP Connector element of your
>   Tomcat server.xml configuration file to an analogous value. Caution:
>   keepAliveTimeout and connectionTimeout must be given in milliseconds.
>   So if you set JK connection_pool_timeout to 600, you should set Tomcat
>   keepAliveTimeout or connectionTimeout to 600000.

Comment: This refers to the connection(s) from a webserver to Tomcat, not the threads used by Tomcat to handle requests.